# Angular PWA service worker tries to load index.html in offline mode

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I configured my angular app with "ng add @angular/pwa".
Here is my setup:

Angular: 14.0.3

@angular/service-worker: 14.2.0

```
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ],
        "urls": [
        ]
      }     
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(svg|cur|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|webp|avif|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Localy under localhost:8080 the app is working fine (also on offline mode). But when I deploy it on the server, it does not work on offline mode. It tries to load again index.html.

As seen in the screenshot below I get the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 ()

[image: As seen in the screenshot I get the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 ()]

Comment: I found the solution to the problem somehow. I went to chrome debug tab "Application"->"Service Worker". I updated the service worker and deleted an old one. After that it started to work

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem is still present when the internet is really off.